# Должно выводить через секунды числа от 10 до 0, вместо этого выводит просто 10

Tags: python, многопоточность

```
import time
from threading import Thread
i=0
def timee():
    global i
    for i in range (10, 0, -1):
        time.sleep(1)
        
Thread(target=timee).start()    
print(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def timee():
    for i in range(10, 0, -1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)

Thread(target=timee).start()
```

Глобал не нужен. Достаточно определить i внутри timee. Выводить цифры нужно при каждой итерации цикла.

Дополнение:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

list =[]

def timee():
    global list
    for i in range(10, 0, -1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        list.append(i)

thread = Thread(target=timee)
thread.start()
thread.join()
print(list)
```

Comment: Как тогда значение переменной i передать другой переменной не входящую в функцию?

Comment: Если вам нужно сохранить результат, то конечно можно определить глобальную переменную, скажем список и добавлять туда при каждой итерации цикла i.

Comment: @nekiy дополнил ответ.

Comment: А поток вообще нужен консольному приложению?

Comment: @Amgarak спасибо большое